# убрать отступы у блоков flex

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Между линиями блоков есть равные отступы, я не понимаю как от них избавиться, чтобы все блоки прижались к левому краю, или к правому

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex__item {
 height: 70px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: green;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
        <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить `align-content: flex-start;` родительскому контейнеру

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 400px;
 max-height: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex__item {
 height: 70px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: green;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
 <div class="flex__item"></div>
</div>
```